# Windows can't connect more than 64k concurrency outgoing connection

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, tcpip, golang

I'm trying to make 100k concurrency outgoing connection from one pc to my local server.
My program can use specific ip on each connection.

Goal : 1 pc have around 100k concurrency outgoing connection.

Problem :
After creating about 64k connection, i always got error on client-side :
"dial tcp bind: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full."
I believe this is client side problem.

Already trying :

1. set maximum port to 65534 via regedit (both client and server)
2. using 7 ip on 1 port lan (client) --> 1 ip on 1 port lan (server) (still error)
3. using 7 ip on 1 port lan (client) --> 2 ip on 1 port lan (server) (still error)
4. using 7 ip on 7 port lan (client) --> 1 ip on 1 port lan (server) (still error)
5. using 7 ip on 7 port lan (client) --> 2 ip on 1 port lan (server) (still error)
6. using 7 ip on 7 port lan (client) --> 2 ip on 2 port lan (server) (still error)

Note :

- number 2 - 6 : each ip handle about 14300 connection.
- Ip on client : 192.168.1.31 /24 - 192.168.1.37 /24
- Ip on server : 192.168.1.20 /24 and 192.168.1.21/24
- both client and server using windows 10.

I'm browsing on many website about this case.
Conclusion based on my browsing, this problem is related to TCP rules.
Some people wrote that 1 Ip can handle maximum 65535 TCP connection.
But, in my case, i use 7 ip on 7 port lan and still get error.
Any suggestion or answer very appreciated.

Comment: The limit is on the number of total *connections in the computer*. IP has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @harrymc, do you have any article or something that i can read about your argument? 

I already stuck since yesterday. 
I found many people says 65534 port is per IP. 

you can read about that in this : [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/533611/how-do-high-traffic-sites-service-more-than-65535-tcp-connections)

Comment: Your article is about Windows Server which is less limited on *incoming* connections, not about Windows 10 outgoing ones. And a port can have only one IP.

Comment: @harrymc, thank you for your response. 

yes, on that article is using windows server. Next time i will consider to try install windows server.    

Btw, 1 port ethernet can use more than one IP. You can try it.